# Pusher Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of

Tags: java, javascript, pusher

I have JavaScript code in one HTML file from which I am calling server for authentication:

```
<html>
<script>
<head>
    var options = { authEndpoint: "api/pusher.json?socket_id=9900&channel_name=presence-channel" }
    var pusher = new Pusher('98384343434343434', options);
    pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
        console.log("connected");
        socketId = pusher.connection.socket_id;
        console.log("socketId" + socketId);
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-channel');
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

And on the server the code is as below:

```
import com.pusher.rest.Pusher;
import com.pusher.rest.data.PresenceUser;
import com.webapp.actions.BusinessApiAction;


@Path("/api/pusher")
public class PusherAction extends BusinessApiAction {
    @POST

    @Produces({ "application/Json", "application/xml" })
    public Response pusher(@Context ServletContext context, @Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res, @FormParam("socket_id") String socketId, @FormParam("channel_name") String channelName) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("\n\n===channel==> " + channelName + "\t socket id-->" + socketId);

        Pusher pusher = new Pusher("92063", "3055e2b132174078348c", "52cfe6c7ecb8420ad981");
        String userId = "5433d5da97d88628ec000300";
        Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("name", "Phil Leggetter");

        String authBody = pusher.authenticate(socketId, channelName, new PresenceUser(userId, userInfo));
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(authBody);
        System.out.println("\n\n===authBody==> " + j.getString("auth"));
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> channelData = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("auth", j.getString("auth"));
        JSONObject ch = new JSONObject(j.getString("channel_data"));
        channelData.put("user_id", ch.getString("user_id"));
        channelData.put("user_info", userInfo);
        map.put("channel_data", ch.toString());

        return sendDataResponse(map);
        }

}
```

The returned response is 200 but Pusher is giving this error:
Error in the pusher logger--

```
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"3055e2b132174078348c:980bf9a6d3a61d280d181785ccacd0e5e7999776085403f2d9bfe688842b8fe7","channel_data":"{\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"Phil Leggetter\"},\"user_id\":\"5433d5da97d88628ec000300\"}","channel":"presence-user2"}}

Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":null,"message":"Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of 41797.10543542:presence-user2:{\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"Phil Leggetter\"},\"user_id\":\"5433d5da97d88628ec000300\"}, but got 980bf9a6d3a61d280d181785ccacd0e5e7999776085403f2d9bfe688842b8fe7"}}

Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of 41797.10543542:presence-user2:{\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"Phil Leggetter\"},\"user_id\":\"5433d5da97d88628ec000300\"}, but got 980bf9a6d3a61d280d181785ccacd0e5e7999776085403f2d9bfe688842b8fe7"}}}
```

Comment: you've shared your application secret above. Could you please make sure that you reset your application secret within the Pusher dashboard? You can do that from the App Keys -> App Credentials section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authBody` that is returned from `pusher.authenticate` should provide you with everything you need to respond to the client request. You just need to make sure that `sendDataResponse` send the `authBody` back as the body of the response as JSON.

I've updated the example you've provided to remove the lines that aren't required:

```
@Path("/api/pusher")
public class PusherAction extends BusinessApiAction {
    @POST

    @Produces({ "application/Json", "application/xml" })
    public Response pusher(@Context ServletContext context, @Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res, @FormParam("socket_id") String socketId, @FormParam("channel_name") String channelName) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("\n\n===channel==> " + channelName + "\t socket id-->" + socketId);

        Pusher pusher = new Pusher(APP_ID, APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        String userId = "5433d5da97d88628ec000300";
        Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("name", "Phil Leggetter");

        String authBody = pusher.authenticate(socketId, channelName, new PresenceUser(userId, userInfo));

        return sendDataResponse(authBody);
    }

}
```

The pusher-rest-java library README show the additional functionality that was present isn't required:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-rest-java#authenticating-presence-channels

Comment: Thanks @leggetter for your response , i tried using var options={authEndpoint: "api/pusher.json" }; but i got the error paramter[socketId] should not be null. Am i missing something?

Comment: It should be `socket_id` and not `socketId`.

Comment: @Kamini could you please update the question providing more information on the `pusher.json` handling code? e.g. fetching the query parameters.

Comment: @Kamini fantastic! Could you please mark my response as the answer?

Comment: just wanted to know about client to client communication, now i have 2 html files whenever i wrote in server api/pusher 
Result result = pusher.trigger(channelName, "client-event", authBody);
and in client1.html wrote 
channel.bind('client-event', function(data) {
 alert("data from server api-->"+data);
});
here i got the alert whatever authbody data m sending,
but i want it to be done by client to client communication,i tried using in one client2.html
channel.trigger('client-event',{ data: 'hello client1'});
but not getting the alert in other client1.html where m binding that event